# (PyMongo) - Parameters of function find_one_and_update()

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am receiving a generic Django error on the line of code listed below. I am having a hard time understanding the pymongo docs on how the parameters are to be set up for this [function](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update). I am thinking i wrote it incorrectly. I have a collection of request documents. Each request document has a "request" key with a value(subreddit_name + "F"). This is what i would like to query and find the document by. Each document also have a "pdone" key with a value(pdone variable). This is the key-value inside the document that i would like to change.

Line of code where the error occurs:

```
 self.collection_requests.find_one_and_update({'request': self.subreddit_name + "F"}, {'pdone': pdone}, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

Here is an insert for a document of the collection:

```
collection_requests.insert({'request': subreddit_name + "F", 'pdone': 0})
```

Edit: still receiving the same error at the same line of code after changing it to: `self.collection_requests.find_one_and_update({'request': self.subreddit_name + "F"}, {'$set': {'pdone': pdone}}, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)`

Comment: and the question is ?
what parameter exactly you don't understand ?
can you post a couple of sample collection documents ?

Comment: my django server is failing on this line of code so i am assuming that i must have written it wrong. I am not getting any specific error, just a "POST /data/ HTTP/1.1" 500 90359" which isn't related to mongodb. Did i specify the parameters correctly? I added an insert as an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hm...  it seems you forget to specify the [update operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/)
try something like:

```
self.collection_requests.find_one_and_update({'request': self.subreddit_name + "F"}, {'$set': {'pdone': pdone}}, return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER)
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesnt change anything for me. I verified that the insert statement worked(as shown through the shell) and i even hardcoded the values instead of using variables. I am still getting a "POST /data/ HTTP/1.1" 500 90372 error on this very line.

Comment: The example above works ok with me: 
can you check pymongo's version ( find_one_and_update is new needs version >3.0).
Also try   return_document = True (in case ReturnDocument has not been imported)